# Где брать Задачи для опыта?

Tags: php

Где можно брать **задачи** (задания) для получения опыта? Допустим, для того же **php**. Ну и не только.

Comment: Тривиальные или практические? Если практические, то могу на вскидку: интернет-казино, кибер-анархисткая соцсеть, видео-чат знакомств, поиск музыки по насвистыванию, поиск блюд по ингридиентам, поиск фильма по сюжету

Comment: как сказал @asianirish  вариантов полно, лучше чем придумывать что-то свое "супер-оригинальное" смотреть какие сайты/решения существуют и делать их с нуля(или почти), быстрее опыта наберетесь.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Есть несколько способов:

1. Создать свой проект, постепенно усложняя его. Начать с сайта-визитки (добавить форму обратной связи, или калькулятор, например)
2. В сети много лабораторных работ по любому языку программирования, можно накачать и "прокачивать" свои скиллы.
3. На этом форуме часто задают вопросы, их тоже можно рассматривать как своего рода задачи.

Comment: К вашему ответу можно было бы добавить ссылки на некоторые источники.